# Return post values with libcurl as std::string

Tags: c++, libcurl

How do you extract the value in `id` field in the form and declare it as a `std::string`

When this function is called it makes a post request to the link provided and outputs the result to command line on the client side

```
int push_(void)
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    /* get a curl handle */
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
           just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
           data. */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/api/0000/push");
        /* Now specify the POST data */


        // the form on the server side has a single field 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=");



        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

id provided as input
`fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`

Server response

```
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="/login">/login</a>.
```

I got this far to extracting the id value but I don't know how to split the id from the html tags

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a callback function `CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_StdString` to get the data out of the post request

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

size_t CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_StdString(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string* s)
{
    size_t newLength = size * nmemb;
    try
    {
        s->append((char*)contents, newLength);
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc& e)
    {
        //handle memory problem
        return 0;
    }
    return newLength;
}

std::string h3ll0() {
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    std::string s;
    if (curl)
    {

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "localhost/api/0000/hello");
        // Add post data to get the command line from the server post request 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=");
        // A calback function that copies the data from the post request output 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_StdString);
        // Write the copied data to the variable s to return it 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);


        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    //std::cout << s << std::endl;

    //std::cout << "Program finished!" << std::endl;
    return s;
}

int main() {
    std::string result = h3ll0();
    std::cout << result << std::endl; 
}
```